# select one radio button for each row

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I am doing an Employees Evaluation System, I am now at the evaluation sheet management.

To display the criteria to rate, I used do while loop [radio button were included to the loop].
Here's my code:

```
<fieldset>
<table border="1">
<tr><br />
<th width="700px">AREAS TO RATE</th>
<th width="100px">1</th>
<th width="100px">2</th>
<th width="100px">3</th>
<th width="100px">4</th>
</tr>

<?php
$rates="select * from tbl_torateareas;";
$raters=mysqli_query($con,$rates);
$raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters);?>

<?php do{?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $raterows['torateareas'];?></td>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad" /></th>
</tr>

<?php }while($raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters)); ?>

</table>
</fieldset>
```

To select one radio button, I named all the radio buttons with the same name [name is:  **rad**]. When I did this, only one radio button is selected for the entire table. As in, for out of **10 rows in my table--only 1 radio button was selected**  which was supposedly, **one radio button for each row**. Hmmmmmmm.

Help with this please. Thanks!

Comment: Change the name of radio for each row :)

Comment: How am i going to change it Sir? I used loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MarcoMura is right. E.g. create adittional variable $i=0, increment it each loop and add it to your names like rad0 in first row, rad1 in second, etc.

While [@Pupil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841760/pupil) [expanded my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521518/1713660) and asked to mark it as a solution, I know more usefull one. The idea is to use not incremental number, but `id` (or maybe `element_id`, or how this column is called in your DB) that is likely fetched from your DB too with `select * from tbl_torateareas;`

So the specific input will look like

```
<input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $raterows['id'];?>]" />
```

It gives your an advantage, that you will exactly know which record in you DB was rated, not just the serial number of row in your html table. This will help to avoid errors when table in DB could change before form submitted.

Another pieces of advice:

**1**.You can likely use `<?=` instead of `<?php echo` to make your code more readable if you have PHP 5.4+ or `short_open_tag = yes` [Click to look the echo() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

**2**. mixing `td` and `th` here is unreasonable, unless you make first cell `th` because it's a heading, and all others `td`, though it's still valid

**3**. your loop is exessive, you don't need to fetch result first, then to wait if it fetches in `while()` in the end, just use common [while()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) syntax

```
while($raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters)) {
    // do all the stuff
}
```

instead of

```
$raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters);
do {
    // stuff
}
while($raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters));
```

I know your question was alredy answered, but maybe this will help to make better code in future.

Comment: The reason why Im using do while loop instead of while loop, Sir is-- I noticed that when i am using while loop, the first row of my table_db wasnt displayed. :D HAHAHAHA.. hmm

Comment: Oh my gosh, Sir! Your answer was the exact thing that I was looking for :) That <input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $raterows['id'];?>]" /> part is the solution! THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add a counter in your loop.

You are assigning same `name` to all radio buttons, that is why they are the same.

```
<?php do{
$i=0;
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $raterows['torateareas'];?></td>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
</tr>

<?php
++$i
}while($raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters)); ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $raterows['torateareas'];?></td>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
```

And in your submit radio code, loop over the posted values.

Like:

```
<?php
if (! empty($_POST['rad'])) {
  $j=0;
  foreach ($_POST['rad'] as $rad) {
    // Access your radio buttons code here.
    ++$j;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I got your point in your answer, Sir. I copied this part of the code <?php do{
$i=0;
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $raterows['torateareas'];?></td>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
<th><input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $i;?>]" /></th>
</tr>

<?php
++$i
}while($raterows=mysqli_fetch_array($raters)); ?>

Comment: but it only selects one radio button for entire table. would you check the codes please....

Comment: @Czarinaaaaa29, yes, it gives you only one posted variable. But, you have different $i, please work on that and you will get desired results.

Comment: What should be your checkbox groups?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67105/discussion-between-pupil-and-czarinaaaaa29).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution. Thanks for further elaboration sir Vladkras!

```
<input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $raterows['id'];?>]" />
```

Comment: You don't need to repost your solution again, just mark the correct answer.